# In flash how do determine what object you touch?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

I am making a tapping racing game for ios/iphone/ipad. I have 3 object that has a touchevent listener. When the cars have been touched or tap, they don't move. Is there a way to determine what object you are touching? I have tried e.currentTarget but that doesn't work. Here is the code i tried.

Thanks you for any tip, help or advice you have.

```
//has been added 
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
//

cars0.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, gasOn);
cars1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, gasOn);
cars2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, gasOn);

private function gasOn(e:TouchEvent):void {
        e.currentTarget.x+=10;
}
```

Comment: Your code is right. Which simulator you have tried?

Comment: I am not using a simulator, I am deploying it to the Ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading the Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#propertySummary) tells us that Events, such as TouchEvents, do have properties called `target` and `currentTarget`.

As the name implies, the target properties tell us who was clicked.

Try the following:

```
function gasOn(e:TouchEvent):void{
   if(e.target == cars0){
       //you clicked cars0
   }else if(e.target == cars1){
       //you clicked cars1
   }else if(e.target == cars2){
       //you clicked cars2
   }
}
```

If this doesn't work, you could try casting the event.target to the Class of cars (I assume it's a separate class?). i.e.:

```
function gasOn(e:TouchEvent):void{
    //Car in this case would be your Class for the cars objects
    var car:Car = e.target as Car;
    if(car == cars0){...//same as above
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up casting it.